# Brute force traveling salesman: Why is Haskell so much slower than C?

Tags: performance, haskell, compare, ghc

I originally wrote a functional brute force search (ADT representation for Cities, tuples of Cities as indices for the distances Array, lazily producing permutations with `Data.List.permutations` and consuming them with a strict left fold), but that was painfully slow. I managed to speed it up by a factor of 3 by successively rewriting it in a more imperative fashion and using Heap's algorithm for permutations, but directly translating the result into (badly written) C is faster by another factor of 10! What is going on?

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections, BangPatterns, ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.Array.Base (unsafeAt)
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as M
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import Data.Word (Word)
import Data.IORef
import GHC.Arr (Ix(..)) 
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Monad

import Data.Array.Storable
import Foreign.Ptr (Ptr)
import Foreign.C (CInt)

import Criterion.Main

distances :: UArray Int Word
distances = listArray (0, 255) [0,629,1023,1470,1276,915,894,1199,760,795,676,903,1394,350,647,922,629,
                                0,556,1312,674,1097,317,946,784,504,1228,276,1254,878,712,1236,1023,556,
                                0,861,408,977,280,480,1340,288,1424,533,822,1346,1267,1198,1470,1312,861,
                                0,1196,751,1125,382,2052,809,1476,1381,78,1817,1957,980,1276,674,408,1196,
                                0,1384,383,837,1370,676,1777,469,1173,1551,1327,1600,915,1097,977,751,1384,
                                0,1103,722,1641,719,730,1303,676,1223,1530,249,894,317,280,1125,383,1103,
                                0,743,1083,392,1409,256,1079,1178,1019,1293,1199,946,480,382,837,722,743,
                                0,1708,454,1366,999,343,1549,1618,972,760,784,1340,2052,1370,1641,1083,1708,
                                0,1253,1392,901,1986,640,113,1679,795,504,288,809,676,719,392,454,1253,
                                0,1138,623,749,1136,1164,925,676,1228,1424,1476,1777,730,1409,1366,1392,1138,
                                0,1502,1399,786,1283,551,903,276,533,1381,469,1303,256,999,901,623,1502,
                                0,1335,1127,857,1469,1394,1254,822,78,1173,676,1079,343,1986,749,1399,1335,
                                0,1741,1889,908,350,878,1346,1817,1551,1223,1178,1549,640,1136,786,1127,1741,
                                0,543,1182,647,712,1267,1957,1327,1530,1019,1618,113,1164,1283,857,1889,543,
                                0,1566,922,1236,1198,980,1600,249,1293,972,1679,925,551,1469,908,1182,1566,0]

tsp_mut :: [Int] -> IO ([Int], Word) 
tsp_mut [] = error "empty list"
tsp_mut cs = do
    route <- V.thaw . V.fromList $ cs
    let  l = length cs -1 
         dis a b= unsafeAt distances $ 16*a + b
         f (prev, !acc) c = (c, acc + dis prev c)  
         len = V.unsafeFreeze route >>=  return . snd . (\v -> V.foldl' f (V.unsafeLast v, 0) v) 
    ref <- newIORef . (cs,) =<< len
    let permut 0 = do
                !l <- len 
                (_, ol) <- readIORef ref
                when (l < ol) (writeIORef ref . (,l) . V.toList =<< V.freeze route)
        permut n = let op = if odd n then const 0 else id
                    in forM_ [0..n] (\ i -> permut (n-1) >> M.unsafeSwap route (op i) n)             
    permut l >> readIORef ref 


foreign import ccall unsafe "tsp_c"
        c_tsp_c :: Int -> Ptr CInt ->  IO Word
tsp_c :: [Int] -> IO ([Int], Word)
tsp_c cs = do
        let l=length cs
        marr <- newListArray (0, l-1) $ map fromIntegral cs
        r <- withStorableArray marr $ c_tsp_c l 
        list <-getElems marr
        return (map fromIntegral list, fromIntegral r)

main = defaultMain [ pertestIO "tsp_mut" tsp_mut,
                      pertestIO "tsp_c" tsp_c ]              
        where 
           pertestIO str f = bgroup str $ map (uncurry bench . (show &&&  nfIO . (f . (`take` [0..15])))) [6..11]
```

Here the C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned int word;

word distances[] = { 0,629,1023,1470,1276,915,894,1199,760,795,676,903,1394,350,647,922,629,
                     0,556,1312,674,1097,317,946,784,504,1228,276,1254,878,712,1236,1023,556,
                     0,861,408,977,280,480,1340,288,1424,533,822,1346,1267,1198,1470,1312,861,
                     0,1196,751,1125,382,2052,809,1476,1381,78,1817,1957,980,1276,674,408,1196,
                     0,1384,383,837,1370,676,1777,469,1173,1551,1327,1600,915,1097,977,751,1384,
                     0,1103,722,1641,719,730,1303,676,1223,1530,249,894,317,280,1125,383,1103,
                     0,743,1083,392,1409,256,1079,1178,1019,1293,1199,946,480,382,837,722,743,
                     0,1708,454,1366,999,343,1549,1618,972,760,784,1340,2052,1370,1641,1083,1708,
                     0,1253,1392,901,1986,640,113,1679,795,504,288,809,676,719,392,454,1253,
                     0,1138,623,749,1136,1164,925,676,1228,1424,1476,1777,730,1409,1366,1392,1138,
                     0,1502,1399,786,1283,551,903,276,533,1381,469,1303,256,999,901,623,1502,
                     0,1335,1127,857,1469,1394,1254,822,78,1173,676,1079,343,1986,749,1399,1335,
                     0,1741,1889,908,350,878,1346,1817,1551,1223,1178,1549,640,1136,786,1127,1741,
                     0,543,1182,647,712,1267,1957,1327,1530,1019,1618,113,1164,1283,857,1889,543,
                     0,1566,922,1236,1198,980,1600,249,1293,972,1679,925,551,1469,908,1182,1566,0}; 

word dist (int a, int b) {
      return distances[16*a+b];
}

int len (int cities[], int length) {
   int l = dist(cities[length-1], cities[0]);
   int i;
   for (i=0; i < length-1; i++ ) {
        l +=dist(cities[i], cities[i+1]);
   }
   return l;
}

int *route, *bestRoute; 
word minL; 
int sz, size, cntr;

void permut (int n){
    if (n==0) { 
        cntr++;
        int l=len(route, sz);
        if (l<minL) {
            memcpy(bestRoute, route,size);
            minL=l;
            }
        return;    
        }
    int i, swap, temp; 
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++) {
        permut(n-1);
        swap=n% 2 ? i : 0;
        temp=route[swap];
        route[swap]=route[n];
        route[n]=temp; 
    }         
}

word tsp_c (int length, int cities[]) {
    size= length * sizeof(int);
    cntr=0;
    sz=length;
    route = malloc(size); 
    bestRoute = malloc(size); 
    memcpy( route, cities, size); 
    memcpy( bestRoute, cities, size); 
    minL = len (cities, length);
    permut(length-1); 
    memcpy(cities, bestRoute, length * sizeof(int)); 
    free(route);
    free(bestRoute); 
    /* printf("permutations: %d", cntr); */
    return minL;
}
```

I used the 64 bit version of GHC 7.8.3 on Windows with `-O2`

Comment: This seems like an interesting (even though brief) read: http://www.quora.com/Is-Haskell-as-fast-as-C++-If-not-why-not

Comment: Your Haskell code is not equivalent to the C code. It uses different data structures, different control structures, and allocates a lot. If you want identical performance, use identical code. Or write in idiomatic Haskell (using Vector)

Comment: Just tried your criterion benchmark with `Data.List.permutations` instead of `tsp_mut`. Result? The Haskell implementation finishes in ~2ns for _each_ example, whereas `tsp_c` needs around 10^(i-5)µs. Did you use optimization flags?

Comment: @Zeta: Sounds like GHC optimized the execution away entirely in your case. Try it with forcing evaluation (nf) or printing the result or something. No manner of optimization will brute force search 40 million permutations in 2ns.

Comment: @Don Stewart: Vector library was the first thing I tried. Unfortunately I couldn't manage to come up with any way to generate permutations in a fusable way. Do you have any concrete suggestions for "using identical code"? I tried to index into the route MVector with a `forM` before, but that actually made the code slower. Or do you mean just use C if you want perfomance within an order of magnitude of C?

Comment: @willy-s: It did, although I used `nf`. Meh :/, the performance of `Data.List.permuations` is really bad. However, using `Vector`, I got ~500ns each, but I haven't tested whether it actually evaluated the vector. Going to do that later, but for now I'm leaving [the code here](http://lpaste.net/314640520896839680).

Comment: Unless I'm blind your permut is missing the recursive call that would make it Heap's algorithm and therefore only tries a single permutation.

Comment: @willy-s: Nope, you aren't blind, the recursive call is indeed missing, wrote that down in a hurry (which also explains the same time regardless of input size).

Answer (score 1):

To quote the Haskell web site:

> In applications where performance is required at any cost, or when the
>   goal is detailed tuning of a low-level algorithm, an imperative
>   language like C would probably be a better choice than Haskell,
>   exactly because it provides more intimate control over the exact way
>   in which the computation is carried out ...

Another way to look at it:  C 'instructions' are closer to the hardware, so it inherently has an advantage.  This is especially obvious when you translate from a 'high' level language directly to C.

On the other hand, the advantage of a high level language is that you focus on the bigger picture, where you can (usually) get more optimizing done faster.